# QGIS Plugin - Automatically update field names combo box using data from another combo box

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating my very first QGIS plugin using two combo boxes - one to select a layer and the other to select a field.

Whilst the layer selection feature seems to work, the field name combo box is not updated when a new layer is selected.

My code is as follows...

```
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]

    fields = [field.name() for field in selectedLayer.pendingFields() ]
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(fields)
```

Does anyone happen to know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could put most of your code in a function which will be run every time a user changes the current layer from the combobox. For example, you could use something like:

```
self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer_list = []
for layer in layers:
    layer_list.append(layer.name())
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)

def field_select():
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    fields = [field.name() for field in selectedLayer.pendingFields()]
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(fields)

# This connects the function to the layer combobox when changed
self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(field_select)
```

Comment: @JamieTasker - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. On my version, the first layer combox box get filled automatically from the start and it doesn't allow the selection of the associated field. It's only when the layer is actually selected 'by hand' that the field combo box update itself. Any idea to start with empty combo boxes?

Comment: @Leo - One way could be to add an empty item to the beginning of the list. So for the first combo box after `layer_list = []`, add `layer_list.append('')`. But you would probably need to include an `if` statement in the `field_select()` function to check if a layer is selected or an empty item is selected from the first combo box. If the latter then clear the combo box else show the list of fields. There might be an easier way but it's been a while since I worked on something like this :)

Comment: Great idea! I almost got it to work, but now the list of fields being shown is for the layer following the one selected. Also, the list of fields now gets to double everytime the layer selected changes. Would you know how to correct that?

Comment: @Leo 1: It is because the index of the second combo box no longer matches the index of the first (because of the added empty item). I would instead identify the layer using the **name**. So you could try replacing `selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()` with `selectedLayerText = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText()`; and `selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]` with `selectedLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(str(selectedLayerText))[0]`. 2: Make sure before any items are added to the second combo box that it is cleared: `self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, that's so nice of you to have taken the time. Learned a lot doing it. For anyone reading this, it is also useful to had a if/else after selectedLayerText to avoid a 'list out of range' error if the first empty ' ' layer is selected again by mistake. If selected layer is ' ' self.dlg.comboBox2.clear(). Else: carry on with the rest of def field_select()

Comment: Also in QGIS 3, QgsMapLayerRegistry has been replaced by QgsProject.

Comment: @Leo - Most welcome! Glad you got it working and thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

Just a little update for QGIS 3 users, `layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()` should be replaced by `layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]`